# retrieve data from SCOM DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wont to retrieve data from [OperationsManagerDW] SCOM DB.
i wont to find all monitored devices(servers,application Servers and web services).
i must prepare a report to calculate devices availability(i have some IP servers).
How  can i find where server names are stored,their IP and availability or downtime,something else.
Thank-you!

Comment: what have you tried so far? Can you provide more details such as desired output for the report (including sample data)?

Comment: i have seen tables event.event and some others. i wont to retrieve information about Servers names or devices,their IP addresses and time they have been up ,or down.bcs i have to calculate the availability of  it devices. thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your case , use the reporting view on scom console is the best choice which can give you the downtime and uptime of yours servers. it's easy to set up and you can schedule it .